# python: как записать значение в двумерный массив?

Tags: python

Мне требуется записать значения в двумерный список перебирая значения других списков:

```
    for i, snt in enumerate(text_list):
        for j, wrd in enumerate(dict):
   #         print (i,j)
           matrix[i][j] = snt.count(wrd)
```

Выходит ошибка: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

`print (i,j)` - отрабатывает со всеми значениями индексов так как надо

Answer (score 2):

У Вас ошибка: Выход за границы диапазона списка.

В Python для того, чтобы изменять значение элемента списка по индексу нужно каким-то образом сначала добавить этот элемент в список.

А так будет работать:

```
for i, snt in enumerate(text_list):
    matrix.append([]) # append new sublist to the list
    for j, wrd in enumerate(dict):
        matrix[i].append(snt.count(wrd)) # append the value to the sublist
```

На каждой итерации внешнего цикла мы создаем пустой подсписок и добавляем его в список. Внутренний цикл добавляет элемент в подсписок.

После добавления элементов к ним можно обращаться по индексам.

А функции **print** все равно какие индексы выводить.

Comment: круто! спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать матрицу подсчёта повторений слов в предложениях, заданного текста (как список предложений, заданных как список слов):

```
matrix = [[sentence.count(word) for word in dict_] for sentence in text]
```

В вашем случае ошибка из-за того, что вы вероятно ожидали, что `matrix[i][j] = value` конструкция создаёт новый  `(i, j)` элемент в матрице. В Питоне списки не создают новые элементы с помощью присваивания простым индексам. Поэтому если `matrix[i][j]` не существовал, то присваивание выбросит `IndexError` ошибку.

Comment: и вам спасибо! перестраиваюсь с пхп на питон, а мануала толкового пока не нашел в инете. еще вопрос, а метод count получается же ищет не вхождение слова в предложение, а вхождение подстроки в строку. Что не есть одно и тоже. Если мне нужна именно 
частота слова в предложении, то как быть, есть ли стандартные функции?

Comment: @VladimirVasilev Материалов о Питоне навалом—это один из самых популярных языков.  Для людей знакомых с программированием, можно начать с официального вводного руководства (доступно и в виде книги на русском и online)¶ Я явно написал в ответе, что sentence это список (а не строка) как раз потому что иначе подстроки ищутся в count(). Если не знаете как разбить предложение на отдельные слова, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос: в зависимости от ваших конкретных требований, решение может использовать и простой `words = sentence.split()` вызов, и  regex, и TweetTokenizer из nltk, итд.